# Views are different but rendering same template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

i want to use slug field in both url which is

```
path('<slug:title>/',views.news_read,name="news_read"),
path('<slug:title>/',views.movie_read,name="movie_read"),
```

but both the url picking same template instead of their template  i am trying to create blog site
i don't understand both the url are uniques so why django is picking wrong template

my views for both the url

```
def movie_read(request, title):
    movie = Movie.objects.filter(urltitle=title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Commentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank You For Your Comment')
    else:
        form = Commentform()
    return render(request,'movie_read.html',{'movie':movie,'form':form})

def news_read(request, title):
    news = News.objects.filter(urltitle=title)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Commentform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Thank You For Your Comment')
    else:
        form = Commentform()
    return render(request,'news_read.html',{'news':news,'form':form})
```

but i when do some change like this it work

```
path('<slug:title>/news',views.news_read,name="news_read"),
path('<slug:title>/movie',views.movie_read,name="movie_read"),
```

but this doesn't look good any idea what to do solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will "fire" the first path that matches the URL. This thus means that for every slug you enter, `news_read` will fire.

You can solve this by trying to query *both* models, and then decide which to use, like:

```
def my_view(request, title):
    is_movie = Movie.objects.filter(urltitle=title).exists()
    if is_movie:
        return movie_read(request, title)
    else:
        return news_read(request, title)

def movie_read(request, title):
    # …

def news_read(request, title):
    # …
```

and then thus trigger the `my_view` function if it is a slug:

```
path('<slug:title>/', views.my_view, name='news-movie-read'),
```

but a more elegant solution is to simply define two *non-overlapping* URL patterns:

```
path('news/<slug:title>/', views.news_read,name='news_read'),
path('movie/<slug:title>/', views.movie_read,name='movie_read'),
```

This also will prevent clashes where a `Movie` object and a `News` object have both the same `url_title` since in that case, it will always use the `movie_read` view.

Comment: thank you for your answer but isn't when slug is unique this make it different

Comment: @Blackranger: the slugs are indeed unique. But the database can only enforce uniqness for items in the same table. In other words, it is possible to create a `Movie` named `foobar`, and a `News` named `foobar`.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that tou url path is the same, that is why django picking wrong view.
Try to change urls to this:
path('news/slug:title/',views.news_read,name="news_read"),
path('movies/slug:title/',views.movie_read,name="movie_read"),